# Generate a unique code for every table row in Cognito Forms?

Tags: cognito-forms

Is it possible to generate a unique code for every row of a table entry?
I am setting up a daily reporting tool for projects. I need to be able to create a form that a company a) completes their company details, and then b) 'registers' their projects. I need each project to assign or generate a unique code or identifier per project. The reason for this is that a company may have more than one project, so I don't want them to have to fill in a new form with all the company details again per form. I need a unique code for the project so that when they complete daily reporting, they can just enter the code that belongs to that project and complete the report. So I will have two forms - one for all the projects that belong to a certain company, and the second for their daily reporting without having to complete company and project details every day. Is this possible to do with a hidden calculation field and generating string? Simply, I need a unique ID per table row entry, much like the unique ID that generates for a form entry. I need each project to have it's own ID to prevent a company from being able to select another company's project, which is why i can't simply use a lookup field between forms. If I had a unique identifier per table row (project), I could send these unique project codes via the confirmation message or a redirect URL perhaps.

If this isn't possible, is there a workaround to achieve the above scenario?